# Issues with struct declarations

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration

I have a problem, which is that I have a function that fills several aspects of a struct but it gives me an error saying that it has been declared more than once with different types of arguments, but I can't find the problem. Some variable and function names are in Spanish.

```
struct juegos_interano {
    char participantes[60][15];
    char sexo[60];
    int medallas[10][4];
    char deportes_partisipados[60][10];
    char encargado[20];
    int max_persona;
};

struct todos_los_anos {
    struct  juegos_interano primer_ano;
    struct  juegos_interano segundo_ano;
    struct  juegos_interano tercer_ano;
    struct  juegos_interano cuarto_ano;
};

struct todos_los_anos create_random_table()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    struct todos_los_anos all_year;
    
    //200 names
    char names[200][20] = {
        "Juan", "Pedro", "Luis" };
    //Sex in relation to names 
    
    char sex[200] = {
        'M', 'M', 'M' };
    
    char sports[10] = {'n','v','b','t','f','y','k','d','a','p'};
    
    int medals[40] = {1};
    int medallas = 40;
    
    int rand_total_name = 0;
    int rand_total_medallas = 0;
    int rand_name = 0;
    int rand_sport = 0;
    int rand_medals = 0;
    int random = 0;
    int r_name = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    rand_total_name = rand() % 60 +20;
    
    rand_total_medallas = rand() % medallas;
    medallas = medallas - rand_total_medallas;
    
    rand_name = 0;
    rand_sport = 0;
    rand_medals = 0;
    random = 0;
    i = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)
        rand_name = rand() % 200;
        rand_sport = rand() % 10;
        random = rand() % rand_sport;
        rand_medals = rand_medals - random;
        if (rand_medals<0)
            random = random + rand_medals; 
        fill_struct (&all_year.primer_ano, rand_total_name, rand_name, rand_sport, random, rand_total_medallas, i, names, sex, sports, medals);
    
    r_name = rand() % 200;
    strcpy(all_year.primer_ano.encargado, names[r_name]);
    
    rand_total_name = rand() % 60 +20;
    
    rand_total_medallas = rand() % medallas;
    medallas = medallas - rand_total_medallas;
    
    rand_name = 0;
    rand_sport = 0;
    rand_medals = 0;
    random = 0;
    i = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)
        rand_name = rand() % 200;
        rand_sport = rand() % 10;
        random = rand() % rand_sport;
        rand_medals = rand_medals - random;
        if (rand_medals<0)
            random = random + rand_medals; 
        fill_struct (&all_year.segundo_ano, rand_total_name, rand_name, rand_sport, random, rand_total_medallas, i, names, sex, sports, medals);
    
    r_name = rand() % 200;
    strcpy(all_year.segundo_ano.encargado, names[r_name]);
    
    rand_total_name = rand() % 60 +20;
    
    rand_total_medallas = rand() % medallas;
    medallas = medallas - rand_total_medallas;
    // inicializaciones en 0 
    rand_name = 0;
    rand_sport = 0;
    rand_medals = 0;
    random = 0;
    i = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)
        rand_name = rand() % 200;
        rand_sport = rand() % 10;
        random = rand() % rand_sport;
        rand_medals = rand_medals - random;
        if (rand_medals<0)
            random = random + rand_medals; 
        fill_struct (&all_year.tercer_ano, rand_total_name, rand_name, rand_sport, random, rand_total_medallas, i, names, sex, sports, medals);
    
    r_name = rand() % 200;
    strcpy(all_year.tercer_ano.encargado, names[r_name]);
    
    rand_total_name = rand() % 60 +20;
    
    rand_total_medallas = rand() % medallas;
    medallas = medallas - rand_total_medallas;
    
    rand_name = 0;
    rand_sport = 0;
    rand_medals = 0;
    random = 0;
    i = 0;
    
    for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)
        rand_name = rand() % 200;
        rand_sport = rand() % 10;
        random = rand() % rand_sport;
        rand_medals = rand_medals - random;
        if (rand_medals<0)
            random = random + rand_medals; 
        fill_struct (&all_year.cuarto_ano, rand_total_name, rand_name, rand_sport, random, rand_total_medallas, i, names, sex, sports, medals);
    //llenar encargado
    r_name = rand() % 200;
    strcpy(all_year.cuarto_ano.encargado, names[r_name]);
    
    return all_year;

}

void fill_struct(struct juegos_interano *year, int rand_total_name, int rand_numb, int rand_sport, int rand_medals, int rand_total_medallas, int count, char names[200][20], char sex[200], char sports[10], int medals[40])
{
    int i = 0;
    int random = 0;

    strcpy(year->participantes[count], names[rand_numb]);
    year->sexo[count] = sex[rand_numb];
    year->max_persona = rand_total_name;
    
    
    for (i=0; i < rand_sport; i++){
        random = rand() % 10;
        year->deportes_partisipados[count][i] = sports[random];
    }
    
    for (i=0; i< rand_medals; i++){
        do{
            random = rand() % rand_total_medallas;
            if (medals[random]==1){
                if (medals[random]<10){
                    year->medallas[count][i] = 1;
                    medals[random] = 0;        
                }
                else if (medals[random]>=10 && medals[random]<20){
                    year->medallas[count][i] = 2;
                    medals[random] = 0;
                }
                else if (medals[random]>=20 && medals[random]<30){
                    year->medallas[count][i] = 3;
                    medals[random] = 0;
                }
                else if (medals[random]>=30){
                    year->medallas[count][i] = 4;
                    medals[random] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        while(medals[random]==0);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual error? If you're going to include almost 200 lines of code the least you could do is keep the includes at the top.

Comment: I can't see your exact error, but in the code above, (in `create_random_table`)  `fill_struct` is used before its declaration.

Comment: You're missing braces on several  `for` loops. C is not Python.

Comment: Please provide the complete and exact error message (copy&paste as formatted text into the question). What function is declared twice? Do you call some function before you define it without a prototype? Then there is an "implicit declaration" for that function which will assume some default types which may then collide with the real function definition. Edit: It seems that is the case for `fill_struct`. Unless you declare it in some header you did not show...

Comment: C is not Python; indentation does not force the bodies of loops.  You have a loop `for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)` followed by 7 lines indented as if they should be part of the body of the loop.  However, only the first line is actually in the body of the loop.  If you want the other 6 lines to be included, add an open brace `{` before the first line and a close brace `}` after the last line.  (You also skimped on all the header files — please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — aka MRE).

Comment: You call `fill_struct()` before you define it, so old-fashioned C (C90 — not C99 or later) thinks that the function returns an `int`.  You later define it as returning `void`, so the compiler complains.  It should be complaining about the return type rather than the arguments; the implicit declaration doesn't assume anything about the arguments.  Although a compiler might note if you call it with one set of types and define it with another, it certainly is not obligated to do so.  Declare function prototypes before you call the function.  C99 says that's necessary — only C90 allows sloppiness.

Comment: Wow! This is the largest initialization function I have ever seen. Setting world records is not always a good thing. Breaking long code sections up into several smaller functions can be.

Answer (score 0):

At least this issue

**Missing `{}`**

In 4 places.  Example:

```
for (i=0; i < rand_total_name; i++)
{ //Add   
    rand_name = rand() % 200;
    rand_sport = rand() % 10;
    random = rand() % rand_sport;
    rand_medals = rand_medals - random;
    if (rand_medals<0)
        random = random + rand_medals; 
    fill_struct (&all_year.cuarto_ano, rand_total_name, rand_name, rand_sport, random, rand_total_medallas, i, names, sex, sports, medals);
} //Add
```